# Upgrading XMPPFramework - Classes Are Not Detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm trying to upgrade `XMPPFramework` on an old project (many versions has been released since I first used framework).

I have replaced files and changed required settings, but some classes are not detected during compile procedure. I get weird `Expected a type`, `Unknown type name` and `No type or protocol name` errors.

This is happening while I have imported required classes but some classes weirdly are not detected.

Here are some screenshot from just some of the files in framework that are not being compiled while required imports are done :

[image]

Or :

[image]

Any Suggestions ? :-/

EDIT: I can even provide TeamViewer Remote Access if a closer look is required.

Comment: No Views ? No Ideas ? No Suggestions ?

Comment: Hello, Can you have a look at this question. Order of compilation of classes.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105688/expected-a-type-error-pointing-to-the-return-type-of-a-method
Could it be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using XMPPFramework 3.6.5 (latest release version) you can see [`Sample_XMPPFramework.h`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/db543e1b484687768024ce3e78e9f287fbee4aa6/Sample_XMPPFramework.h) in the source tree: you must rename it to `XMPPFramework.h` and include required modules in it.

But you can also use XMPPFramework from Cocoapods (current development version): in that case you need to add `pod "XMPPFramework"` to your `Podfile` and add different "subspecs", e.g. `pod "XMPPFramework/XEP-0054"` will import `XMPPvCardTempModule` into your project