# Swift - "Expected a type" error pointing to function parameter

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm following an iMessage extension tutorial [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-10-imessages-sdk-creating-an-imessages-extension) and one of the functions listed has me perplexed because I've never seen a logical not operator in the signature of the function. According to the tutorial, we are writing a class function that will retrieve data from an endpoint. I'm not sure if the author's intent is to grab data that isn't a post? Also this line of code is throwing an error in Xcode that says "Expected type". [Another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105688/expected-a-type-error-pointing-to-the-return-type-of-a-method) states seeing this error in Objective-C based on file structure however the specified parameter type for this tutorial is listed within the same Swift file.

```
import Foundation

struct Post {
    var title: String?
    var score: NSNumber?
    var url: String?
    var domain: String?
}


class RedditAPI {
    static let REDDIT_API_URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/programming.json"

    //a single function that fetches reddit posts.....and takes a completion closure....hmm who is this completion closure for and what will it do?  Is it fired after all of the reddit posts are retrieved from the web server?
    //according to the tutorial, the completion closure  should accept an array of Reddit post objects.
    class func getTopStories(_ completionBlock: ((results: ![Post]) -> Void )){

    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you arbitrarily insert a `!` in there? Remove it and move on to the next error.

Comment: Love it!  I'm never seen a not operator used in this way so I figured you knew more about this @rmaddy I wanted to make sure all bases were covered for my understanding

Comment: @CosmicArrows I would avoid this tutorial. With all the force unwrapping, it's pretty clear the author knows very little about proper swift development.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah and the JSON parsing code is a long way from what anyone should be doing. Poor tutorial with a lot of bad code.